# How to print a dynamic message in a <div> tag using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a message "I have 3 tries left", in this message "3" is dynamic and by default my `<div>` tag is set to *`style="display:none"`* :

```
<div id="triesleft" style="display:none"></div>
```

I am looking for a way to display the above message in a `<div>` dynamically on onchange event of a select box..

I tried with this

```
function triesleftfunc()
{
    var size = document.getElementById('size').value.split('x');
    var sizesqft = size[0]*size[1];
    var trial = document.getElementbyId(tires).value;
    if(sizesqft >= 50 && document.getElementById('options').value == 'Stiched Finish')
    {
        document.getElementById('triesleft').innerHTML = "I have "+trial+" tries left";
        document.getElementById('triesleft').display = "block";

        document.getElementById('options').focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

NOTE I dont need alert Box it looks BAD BAD ....

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById('triesleft').style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
var triesLeft = 3;
document.getElementById("MySelectBox").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("triesleft").innerText = "You have " + triesLeft + 
                                                     " tries left.";
    document.getElementById("triesleft").style.display = "block";
    triesleft--;
}
```

And then just do some check on `triesleft` to make sure it's not zero or less.

Comment: Thanks @peirix could you please look at my updated question I have almost similar to your ides.. what corrections are needed in my code...

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is your code not working? If you have a new issue, you might want to post a new question, or just edit your question to include what isn't working. It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery then look at [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plug-in. It supports both blocking message or growl kind of message (the non-intrusive message - for example one thats appear on this site).

Comment: Thanks @Vinay, Nope i am not using jquery I dnt want to

Comment: Don't know if you want a non-intrusive message or a blocking message. You can achieve non-intrusive message relatively easy - u are already sort of doing it in your example - u just need add css/js to control position and dismissal of the message box. For blocking message, its bit too much work in java-script - essential steps involve 1) creating a translucent layer occupying entire screen on top of screen 2) Showing your message on top of this layer and 3) handling scrolling and resizing of window. That's why its better to use some library in such case.